# Form maximize on another form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have an MDI application which contains many child forms

My problem is, on clicking a particular menu, I am opening a form with maximize window in the MDI form. This works fine.

Now if I open another form above the first one, and if i want the second form to be of normal size, i am unable to do it.

Second form also opens with maximized window similar to first one. I want the second form to be of normal small size.

I want to show second form normally and first form maximized.

How can i do that?

```
Private Sub TESTToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TESTToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim f As New newCalendar2("UGHARANI")
        f.Show()
        f.MdiParent = Me
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Sub
```

Comment: How far have you come - codewise. Please post codesnippets

Comment: <pre><code>Private Sub TESTToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TESTToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim f As New newCalendar2("UGHARANI")
        f.Show()
        f.MdiParent = Me
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Sub</code></pre>

Comment: I am unable to add code with vb.net formatting. Please excuse me and tell me how can i add VB.NET code in this forum as a reply.

Comment: It is normal MDI behaviour for every child form to have the same `WindowState` property and you would be ill-advised to try and interfere with that, as it could be confusing to users. Can't you just display the second form on top of the MDI form – i.e. don't set the `MdiParent` property – and make it `TopMost`?

Comment: P.S. You should put your code snippet in the original post and ensure each line has at least four spaces at the start to format it as code.

Comment: @Antagony, so is it not possible to show one form normal above maximized form?

Comment: Not if they're both MDI children in the same container form, no.

Comment: You should try to explain a bit more (in the original post) about what effect you're trying to achieve, and why. It may then be possible to find some solution that works for you.

Comment: @Antagony I just need to show second form normally and the first one maximized.
In my application, I am displaying some form data with maximized form to view full data. Other forms are smaller one so they dont need to be maximized, So i want them to show with their normal size along with the maximized form. This is whay i want

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish: you want the first (data) form to be a kind of background to your MDI application and have the other forms display on top of it, right?

Well one way to do it might be to remove borders from the background form –`FormBorderStyle = None`– and fill-dock it in the MDI parent form. Although it would end up coming to the fore and hiding all your other forms if a user clicked anywhere on it. But if it doesn't require any user interaction you could always use its `Activate` event to send it back to the background, using `Me.SendToBack().`